# How do i make a history calculator in android?

Tags: android

I am making a calculator same as windows calculator. I am stuck at the history feature.  which would be the best UI control to implement the history feature as seen in Windows Calculator?
I also want onclick events on the history.

Comment: What does the history feature do?

Comment: history feature shows the two operands and an operand involved in the calculation.. which also replaces itself with the latest calculation made and occupies upper position

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you represent a calculation, but you could have a simple class like this:

```
enum Operator {PLUS,MINUS,DIV,MULT};

class Calculation {
    float operand1,operand2;
    Operator operator;
    public Calculation(float op1,float op2,Operator operator){
        this.operand1=op1;
        this.operand1=op2;
        this.operator=operator;
    }
}
```

Then when a calculation is done, create an object of this type and add it to an ArrayList:

```
List<Calculation> history = new ArrayList<Calculation>();// history

history.add(new Calculation(5,5,Operator.PLUS));// add a new `Calculation` to our list
```

Then access the list with `history.get(some_integer)`, based on your UI.

Answer (score 0):

Could you just use a [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/List.html) containing a number of previously entered calculations? If you knew the maximum possible history size in advance, you could just stick with a normal array, but a List will give you more flexibility.

Comment: does List support onclick events?

Comment: Ah sorry, I thought you were talking about the underlying store for your history of calculations. I suggest you update your question to clarify that you're actually asking about which would be the best UI control to implement the history feature as seen in Windows Calculator.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store all the operations and results with an index here. Increase the index every time when you perform an operation.To retrieve the past operation, manipulate the index and you can get the values.You can use Collection API for storing the operations.